# Plotting the mean curve based on multiple curves/dataset in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, approximation, curves

I want to estimate an "Average curve" from curves of multiple trials. I have done this before using approx() , but then I had a fixed set of x-axis values against which y was measured.

In this dataset, values are mixed for both x and y (i.e., there are no fixed values of x for which y has been measured). Instead, different set of x values for every trial.

Is there a way to average curves in these situations (with standard errors)?

Alternatively : 
How would you extract y-values (for a fixed set of x-values) from different curves and construct a new dataframe ?

I have provided a sample dataset (melted) - and the code for plotting the curves for individual trials. 
P1, P2,P3,P4, P5  the names/ID for the individual trials

```
    > dput(head(dat,74))
structure(list(ID = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("LCRA_P1", "LCRA_P2", 
"LCRA_P3", "LCRA_P4", "LCRA_P5", "LCRA_P6", "P1", "P2", "P3", 
"P4", "P5"), class = "factor"), Time = c(170L, 452L, 572L, 692L, 
812L, 932L, 1052L, 1172L, 1292L, 1412L, 1532L, 1652L, 1772L, 
1892L, 2012L, 2132L, 2252L, 54L, 290L, 410L, 530L, 650L, 770L, 
890L, 1010L, 1130L, 1250L, 1370L, 1490L, 1610L, 1730L, 1850L, 
1970L, 115L, 235L, 355L, 475L, 595L, 715L, 835L, 955L, 1075L, 
1195L, 1315L, 1435L, 1555L, 1675L, 1795L, 135L, 201L, 321L, 441L, 
561L, 681L, 801L, 921L, 1041L, 1161L, 1281L, 1401L, 100L, 251L, 
371L, 431L, 491L, 611L, 731L, 791L, 851L, 911L, 971L, 1031L, 
1091L, 1151L), I = c(154.5066034, 138.3819058, 104.8425346, 61.6283449, 
40.34374398, 35.18384073, 29.37894957, 40.34374398, 44.85865933, 
27.44398585, 31.9589012, 41.6337198, 54.53347792, 64.20829652, 
70.65817559, 66.78824815, 66.78824815, 154.5066034, 90.00781278, 
73.88311512, 62.2733328, 61.6283449, 57.75841746, 53.24350211, 
48.08359886, 55.17846583, 51.30853839, 42.92369561, 53.24350211, 
50.66355049, 54.53347792, 38.40878026, 54.53347792, 154.5066034, 
73.88311512, 62.2733328, 61.6283449, 57.75841746, 53.24350211, 
48.08359886, 55.17846583, 51.30853839, 42.92369561, 38.40878026, 
54.53347792, 37.79284177, 35.21289014, 39.08281758, 154.5066034, 
129.997063, 84.84790953, 51.30853839, 40.98873189, 33.24887701, 
29.37894957, 27.44398585, 33.24887701, 33.89386492, 31.9589012, 
31.9589012, 135.1569662, 85.49289744, 48.08359886, 48.08359886, 
22.2840826, 27.44398585, 49.37357467, 51.30853839, 31.9589012, 
28.73396167, 23.57405841, 21.63909469, 9.384324471, 25.50902213
)), .Names = c("ID", "Time", "I"), row.names = c(NA, 74L), class = "data.frame")
```

(The code for plotting is included)

```
> ggplot(dat,aes(x=Time, y = I, colour=ID)+
geom_point()+
labs(x="Time (Seconds)", y ="Infiltration (mm/hour)")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,2500,100))+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,160,10))+
geom_line(aes(group=ID))
```

To average, I used this :

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=Time, y=I))+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_se",mult=1, geom="smooth")
```

The result (the figure below) is not making any sense.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean aside from what you would get from adding a `geom_smooth` that wasn't grouped?

Comment: I do not really follow how geom_smooth fits a curve.  I want to see averaged values with SE at some discrete time intervals. Can you control geom_smooth for its parameters?

Comment: Some of them, yes. Can you maybe post an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Not sure if I can get you an example (then I wouldnt be having this problem)- but I edited to include what I tried with stat_summary and the result I got. 
What I wanted was to average the curves - but I think what happened there is that it has averaged based on the x-values in the dataset (which messes up the average since - it includes only the available y-values at a particular x - and then ends up tracing each and every point giving that zig-zag plot)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what's the exact output you want, but here are a few simple examples you can adapt. I think you still had the color or group set in your `aes` when you made the `geom_smooth`, which is why you have lots of lines. If you want lines or points or any other geom for the different IDs, but then want a single smoothing line that averages *all* the IDs, you need to separate what gets a color or group and what doesn't.

Study up on the arguments to `stat_smooth`—there's a lot you can do to specify the curve it draws, including the method and formula, and arguments depending on the method. Note (from the output `geom_smooth` gives) that the default for a small number of observations is a loess curve, which might be the type of averaging you're looking for.

Here are examples of where you might want to take this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = I)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = ID)) +
  geom_smooth()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = I)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = ID)) +
  geom_smooth(se = F, method = lm)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = I)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = ID), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(size = 0.8, se = F, span = 0.2)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks Camille. I appreciate the detailed response - this is helpful. I agree about setting the grouping under the geom_line/ geom_smooth. The second figure I posted was actually for two different datasets (meant to be two average lines). The last plot you posted is somewhat I was trying for -I will look into stat_smooth/geom_Smooth for better fits .